# How to get the next page/part/view of file, if i read part of file using MapViewOfFile?

Tags: windows, visual-c++, android-mapview, shared-memory, memory-mapped-files

I am trying to use combination of functions CreateFileMapping , MapViewOfFile, FlushViewOfFile.

the total buffer size is more than the mapped view.
example buffer is 50KB. and mapped view is 2KB. in such scenario,
i want to write the  total buffer to a physical file, using the above function.

First part i am able to write to file. but the remaining part how to write to file. I mean, how to move to next page and write the next part of data.

```
    #define MEM_UNIT_SIZE 100
```

-first module...Memory map creator

```
GetTempPath (256, szTmpFile);

GetTempFileName (szTmpFile, pName, 0, szMMFile);
hFile = CreateFile (szMMFile, GENERIC_WRITE | GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_WRITE,
        NULL, CREATE_ALWAYS, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_TEMPORARY, NULL);
HANDLE hFileMMF = CreateFileMapping( hFile ,NULL,PAGE_READWRITE,0,
                   (MEM_UNIT_SIZE),pName)
```

-second module... Memory writer

```
    long lBinarySize = 1000;
    long lPageSize = MEM_UNIT_SIZE;

HANDLE hFileMMF = OpenFileMapping(FILE_MAP_WRITE,FALSE,pMemName);
LPVOID pViewMMFFile = MapViewOfFile(hFileMMF,FILE_MAP_WRITE,0,0, lPageSize );
CMutex mutex (FALSE, _T("Writer"));
mutex.Lock();

try
{
    ASSERT(FALSE);
    CopyMemory(pViewMMFFile,pBinary,lPageSize); // write 

    FlushViewOfFile(pViewMMFFile,lPageSize);  
           // first 100 bytes flushed to file. 
           //how to move to next location and  write next 900 bytes..<---??
}
catch(CException e)
{
    ...
}
```

please share if you have any suggestion.
thanks in advance,
haranadh

Comment: post your code so far for advice on how to achieve the next steps

Comment: Hi, i posted code too. any help from u? also i am searching for sample code how to use setEndOfFile. Thanks.

Comment: I cannot improve on the feedback you got from@Jeremiah really.  Do you know how to get the file size to set an upper bound on your mapping range?

Comment: Sorry, I dont know? because, when i tried, it is failing in second iteration. tried as follows: for(int n =0; n<nCount; ++n)
{DWORD dwFileOffsetHigh = 0;
DWORD dwFileOffsetLow = lUnitSize*n;
LPVOID pViewMMFFile = MapViewOfFile(hFileMMF,FILE_MAP_WRITE,dwFileOffsetHigh,dwFileOffsetLow,MEM_UNIT_SIZE);.....

Comment: When I see these unprotected system calls and nobody caring about failed system calls, then I remember nights debugging software written in C which suddenly started to fail.

Answer (score 2):

Repeat your call to MapViewOfFile with a different range.

Comment: i am sorry to ask again, different range means, i need to call mapview of file multiple times,? or any pointer moving to the number of bytes such things do i need to do? thanks for ur response.

Comment: @HaranadhGupta if your original call didn't specify the entire range of the file, you need to call MapViewOfFile again.  For any reasonable file size, I recommend just mapping the entire file since it is only consuming address space.  Since it looks like this may be a brand new file, you'll want to use SetEndOfFile to extend the file to the appropriate size before mapping the view.  Does that help?

Comment: I dont have control to specify for entire range of file, while mapping. because createFileMapping is done before, and at that time I dont know what could be the size of file to be mapped. i am giving basic size. how to use setEndOffile, in this scenario. any i wil search for that function in google too. thanks for help

Comment: I tried the same way like repeating my call using MapViewOffile. But second iteration it is not working. MapViewFile is throwing access violation error as part of getlasterror. pls help if possible. thanks

Comment: @HaranadhGupta Basically, each time you want to add more to the file, unmap the view, use SetEndOfFile to change the size of the file to be larger, and then remap the view with the larger file size.

Answer (score 0):

as described in the following link,

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366761(v=VS.85).aspx

can you please check "allocation granularity", I think you should use this parameter to set the values for "dwFileOffsetLow" or "dwFileOffsetHigh".