# How to repeat call to MapViewOfFile with a different range on a file, to write bigger buffer.?

Tags: visual-c++, android-mapview, shared-memory, memory-mapped-files, memory-mapping

I am using shared memory functions, to write data into file.
Problem:
When I want to write the buffer 10MB, to file using below function, i am able to write only in first iteration, second iteration i could not write buffer next part in to memory. please help me if any suggestion. or any wrong in the below code. i have only control on this part. i dont have control in other part which has CreateFileMapping.

any thing i need to change in "dwFileOffsetLow" or "dwFileOffsetHigh". from second iteration onwards the 
"MapViewOfFile" returning null. Some place i got input as I need to repeate call MapViewOfFile different ranges. But how to call, any help? [previously asked question on this. For reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8050773/how-to-get-the-next-page-part-view-of-file-if-i-read-part-of-file-using-mapview/8050903#comment9860852_8050903)!

WriteBuffer function i defined as follows:

```
BOOL CWriter::Write(char* pMemName,char* pBinary,long lBuffSize)
{
long lUnitSize = MEM_UNIT_SIZE;
if( lBuffSize <= 0 && lUnitSize <=0 )
    return FALSE;
//Open named file mapping object.
HANDLE hFileMMF = OpenFileMapping(FILE_MAP_WRITE,FALSE,pMemName);

if(hFileMMF == NULL)
{
    DWORD dwErr = GetLastError();
    return (FALSE);
}

int nCount = 0;
nCount = (int)(lBuffSize / lUnitSize) + 1;
for(int n =0; n<nCount; ++n)
{
    DWORD dwFileOffsetHigh = 0;
    DWORD dwFileOffsetLow = lUnitSize*n;

    // Map  view of a file mapping into the address space of a calling process.
    LPVOID pViewMMFFile = MapViewOfFile(hFileMMF,
                        FILE_MAP_WRITE,
                        dwFileOffsetHigh,
                        dwFileOffsetLow,
                        MEM_UNIT_SIZE);
    if( pViewMMFFile == NULL )
        return (FALSE);
    CMutex mutex (FALSE, _T("MIPSMMMutexWriter"));
    CString strTemp;
    strTemp.Format("%s",pBinary);

    // Lock memory, shared amongst processes
    mutex.Lock();
    try
    {
        CopyMemory(pViewMMFFile,pBinary,lUnitSize); // write 
    }
    catch(CException e)
    {
        DWORD dw = ::GetLastError();
        TRACE1("%d",dw);
    }
    mutex.Unlock(); // Unlock shared memory
    //Unmap mapped view of a file from the calling process's address space.
    UnmapViewOfFile(pViewMMFFile);
}
return (TRUE);
}
```

Pls suggestme if any correction i should do. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

as described in the following link,

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366761(v=VS.85).aspx

can you please check "allocation granularity", I think you should use this parameter to set the values for "dwFileOffsetLow" or "dwFileOffsetHigh".

Comment: http://www.codeguru.com/forum/archive/index.php/t-284578.html thanks man. i am trying this too. but still i could not get the solution.

Comment: Arjun, i tried with granularity also. it is failing in second iteration. and it is giving in second iteration as AccessDenied error when i tri with getlasterror it returned errorcode 5. :(

Comment: Hi Arjun, It seems, i need to use setEndOfFile, and SetFilePointer functions. will try ... Found in link: [Mapped File May Not be Automatically Grown](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/125713)